# How do I reload/refresh javascript array in DataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using DataTables to display data from a search function. I'm sure if this was intended method for passing data into DataTables. I'm initializing the DataTable with a blank javascript array. Then I want to populate Datatables in a different function.

I've tried $().DataTable().ajax.reload() and $().DataTable().fnAddData(dataSet) but both didn't work.

https://jsfiddle.net/owxz7e22/3/

```
<table id="test" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dt-responsive">
</table>

<a href="#" onclick="LoadData();">Test</a>


$(document).ready(function ()
    {

        $('#test').DataTable({
            data: dataSet,
            columns: [
                { title: "Name" },
                { title: "Position" },
                { title: "Office" },
                { title: "Extn." },
                { title: "Start date" },
                { title: "Salary" }
            ]
        });
    });

    var dataSet = [];

    function LoadData()
    {
        dataSet = [
                ["Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh", "5421", "2011/04/25", "$320,800"],
                ["Garrett Winters", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "8422", "2011/07/25", "$170,750"],
                ["Ashton Cox", "Junior Technical Author", "San Francisco", "1562", "2009/01/12", "$86,000"],
        ];

        var tbl = $('#test').DataTable();

        tbl.fnClearTable();
        tbl.fnDraw();
        tbl.fnAddData(dataSet);


        //$('#test').DataTable().ajax.reload();

    }
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to store your datatable in a variable and adding rows:
Look here:
https://jsfiddle.net/63235xk2/

```
$(document).ready(function ()
        {
            var dataSet = [];

            var datatable = $('#test').DataTable({
                data: dataSet,
                columns: [
                    { title: "Name" },
                    { title: "Position" },
                    { title: "Office" },
                    { title: "Extn." },
                    { title: "Start date" },
                    { title: "Salary" }
                ]
            });


      $('.asd').on('click',function(){
                dataSet = [
                    ["Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh", "5421", "2011/04/25", "$320,800"],
                    ["Garrett Winters", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "8422", "2011/07/25", "$170,750"],
                    ["Ashton Cox", "Junior Technical Author", "San Francisco", "1562", "2009/01/12", "$86,000"],
          ];

        alert(dataSet.length);

          datatable.clear();
          datatable.rows.add(dataSet);
          datatable.draw();
      });

        });
```

Answer (score 3):

By defining a ajax callback function it make it possible to load from data from an array or any other data source, simple by using ajax.reload `datatable` function.

Also, this solution keeps the state of existent rows.

Example:

```
var table = $('#mytable').DataTable({
        ,ajax: function (data, callback, settings) {
                 callback({ data: table_data }) //reloads data 
             }
});

//at some event, reload the table
 $(#some-button).on('click',  function () {
    table.ajax.reload();
 }
```

Comment: Comma-first style hurts my eyes. In the age of unit tests and syntax checkers it looks like a relic from old ages.  And you're not using it right.

Comment: Just fixed. tks

Comment: There are also missing single quotes and semicolons.  Besides `data` and `ajax` are conflicting options, `data` should be removed.

Comment: True. I didn't realize the 'data' setting was doing nothing. Once again thank you. But, where are single quotes missing?