# DataTable not getting refreshed after AJAX POST response is received onclick of next page

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, flask, datatable

My problem statement is as below:

Display 10 rows per page on DataTable.
When the user clicks on the next page number, use that number in flask to calculate row_count.
Select rows from database that are equal to the above row_count.
Display these selected rows on DataTable.

Following code gives me json response on console.log, but my DataTable is not getting refreshed.

JQuery snippet:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       var buttonCommon = {
        exportOptions: {
            format: {
                body: function ( data, row, column, node ) {
                                return data;
                                }
                            }
                    }
            };

var table = $("#myTable").DataTable({
 "lengthMenu": [
   [10, 25, 50, -1],
   [10, 25, 50, "All"]
 ],
 drawCallback: function() {
   $(".paginate_button", this.api().table().container())
     .on("click", function() {

       var pageNum= table.page.info().page;

        $.ajax({
            data: JSON.stringify({ "pageNum": pageNum }),
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "/my/url",
            success: function(data){
                data = JSON.parse(data);
                $("#myTable").DataTable({
                    data: data.data,
                    columns: [
                            { "data": "name" },
                            { "data": "branch" },
                            { "data": "city" },
                            { "data": "state" },
                            { "data": "country" },
                            { "data": "pin" },
                            { "data": "landmark" },
                            ]
                    })
                }
            })
        })
    }   
})
```

Flask snippet:

```
@my_api.route('/url', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def myfunc():

    conn = get_pgsql_conn_obj()
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    if request.get_json():
        number = request.json['pageNum']
        start_num = number * 20 + 1
        stop_num = start_num + 9

        select_sql = "select name, branch, city, state, country, pin, landmark from (select name, branch, city, state, country, pin, landmark, row_number() over (order by pin) as rnum from table) as r where r.rnum <= {}".format(stop_num)
     
        cursor.execute(select_sql)

        myData = cursor.fetchall()
    
        c_data = []
        for c in myData:
            c_data.append({
                'name': c[0],
                'branch': c[1],
                'city': c[2],
                'state': c[3],
                'country': c[4],
                'pin': c[5],
                'landmark': c[6],
                })
     
        return json.dumps(c_data)

    elif request.get_json() is None:

        number = 0
        select_sql = "select name, branch, city, state, country, pin, landmark from (select name, branch, city, state, country, pin, landmark, row_number() over (order by pin) as rnum from table) as r where r.rnum = 1 or r.rnum <= 20"
        cursor.execute(select_sql)

        myData = cursor.fetchall()


        c_data = []
        for c in myData:
            c_data.append({
                'name': c[0],
                'branch': c[1],
                'city': c[2],
                'state': c[3],
                'country': c[4],
                'pin': c[5],
                'landmark': c[6],
                })

        return render_template('my.html', c_data=c_data)

    else:
    *Do something else*
```

I can see the response in the Network Response something like below:

> [{"name": "XYZ", "branch": "main", "city": "Tokyo", "state": "P3",
> "country": "Japan", "pin": "110011", "landmark": "L1"},{"name": "XYZ",
> "branch": "main", "city": "Tokyo", "state": "P3", "country": "Japan",
> "pin": "110011", "landmark": "L2"},...{"name": "XYZ", "branch":
> "main", "city": "Tokyo", "state": "P3", "country": "Japan", "pin":
> "110011", "landmark": "L30"}]

**EDIT:**

I've tried the following 2 solutions, but still not able to get the datatable refreshed:

Solution 1:

```
 var table = $("#myTable").DataTable({
 "lengthMenu": [
   [10, 25, 50, -1],
   [10, 25, 50, "All"]
 ],
 "columnDefs": [{
    "defaultContent": "-",
    "targets": "_all"
 }],
 drawCallback: function() {
   $(".paginate_button", this.api().table().container())
     .on("click", function() {

       var pageNum= table.page.info().page;

        $.ajax({
            data: JSON.stringify({ "pageNum": pageNum }),
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "/my/url",
            success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                    table.clear();
                    table.rows.add(data);
                    table.draw();
                    }                
         });
     });
    }
});
```

This gives me first 20 records with pagination, i.e 10 records per page.
On clicking page number 2, it returns an array like below on network response:

> [{"name": "XYZ", "branch": "main", "city": "Tokyo", "state": "P3",
> "country": "Japan", "pin": "110011", "landmark": "L1"},{"name": "XYZ",
> "branch": "main", "city": "Tokyo", "state": "P3", "country": "Japan",
> "pin": "110011", "landmark": "L2"},...{"name": "XYZ", "branch":
> "main", "city": "Tokyo", "state": "P3", "country": "Japan", "pin":
> "110011", "landmark": "L30"}]

But there's no change to the datatable.

Solution 2 (As suggested by Mtxz):

```
    var table = $("#myTable").DataTable({
 "lengthMenu": [
   [10, 25, 50, -1],
   [10, 25, 50, "All"]
 ],
});


$(".paginate_button", this.api().table().container())
     .on("click", function() {

       makeRequest();

});

function makeRequest() {
    var pageNum = table.hasOwnProperty('page') ? table.page.info().page : 1;
     if (pageNum > 0) {
            $.ajax({
            data: JSON.stringify({ "pageNum": pageNum }),
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "/my/url",
            success: function(data){
                    var new_data = JSON.parse(data);
                    table.clear();
                    table.rows.add(new_data);
                    table.draw();
                    }
            })

    }

}
```

This gives me first 20 records with pagination, i.e 10 records per page.
On clicking page number 2, It gives me *Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1 at JSON.parse ()*

When I try without JSON.parse, it gives me *DataTables warning: table id=objectTable - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0, column 0*, but returns an array like below on console log, clears the table data, and adds an extra page number 3 (response array has 30 records and length is set to 10 per page):

> 0: {"name": "XYZ", "branch": "main", "city": "Tokyo", "state": "P3",
> "country": "Japan", "pin": "110011", "landmark": "L1"}
> 1: {"name": "XYZ",
> "branch": "main", "city": "Tokyo", "state": "P3", "country": "Japan",
> "pin": "110011", "landmark": "L2"}
> 29: {"name": "XYZ", "branch":
> "main", "city": "Tokyo", "state": "P3", "country": "Japan", "pin":
> "110011", "landmark": "L30"}

Comment: You already have `dataType: "json"` why you are again parsing it `JSON.parse(data)` ? Also , any other error inside browser console ?

Answer (score 0):

From your script, it seems that your re-init your table with each click.
What I would do :

1. **Server-side processing** - Datatable has an `ajax`parameter (check examples [here](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side) and [here](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload())), and a `table.ajax.reload();` reload method. It also has a `ajax.url()` to alter the query URL if you need to add query parameters. So you could directly add your API URL to your datatable instance, and use "server-side" processing. Your API sending the correct paginated JSON collection based on the parameters Datatable will add to the request. (I believe it's possible to customize the ajax request to add an authentication header or else). You should check all `ajax.*` related Datatable documentation pages, also google about "jquery datatable server-side processing PHP example" ([see](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.url())). It's the cleanest way if you want to the sorting, the search, and the pagination working with the remote data source, and of course NOT loading the entire set of data :).
2. From your script logic (using the Datatable `data` parameter)

- make a separate method that will handle the ajax call, with a page parameter. This method will return the `$result` ajax result in a variable
- on page load, and call this method with page 1 to get the ajax `$result`, and init your datatable with this `$result`

`var table = $('#example').DataTable({data: jQuery.parseJSON($result), ...`

- 2.1 *on the ajax success handler, update the `$result` variable with new request-response, and call `table.ajax.reload();` to refresh the datatable and redraw with new data.* **EDIT**: I'm not sure that just using a variable as data source and refreshing will work (but the linked examples does, so it need further tests). I think you'll have to follow something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42794104/how-do-i-reload-refresh-javascript-array-in-datatables) to handle your pagination manually.

Still, it's only the pagination. And the search and sorting will only append in the paginated dataset. To have the full power of search, filtering, sorting without having to load the entire dataset onload: you need server-side processing. To handle the PHP side, you can simply put your API url as `ajax` parameter, and on your PHP side dump the entire `$_GET` variable while changing sorting, filtering, search on the frontend. So you'll see how Datatable handles the filtering parameters, and be able to adapt your database queries to take those parameters in consideration, along with pagination: server-side processing.

3. Examples:

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42794104/how-do-i-reload-refresh-javascript-array-in-datatables) is about updating the dataset with new data and can be adapted to your needs.
[This post](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/38969/reload-refresh-table-after-event) and the related comments, as it's a similar case (and it's this example that also uses `data` parameter with a custom ajax handling, that the refresh is also working in this case, with a variable for `data`)

Here is something I've NOT tested that could inspire you:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var buttonCommon = {
        exportOptions: {
            format: {
                body: function (data, row, column, node) {
                    return data;
                }
            }
        }
    };

    //init table with empty data
    var table = $("#myTable").DataTable({
        "lengthMenu": [
            [10, 25, 50, -1],
            [10, 25, 50, "All"]
        ],
        data: []
    });

    //on button click
    $(".paginate_button", this.api().table().container())
        .on("click", function () {
            makeRequest();
            
            //this is from the example where ajax.reloads works when the data is a variable that is updated by a custom ajax handler
            //From this example, it seems that the ajax reload also works when the data is a variable - todo make some test
            //table.ajax.reload();
        })

    //make async request
    function makeRequest() {
        var pageNum = table.hasOwnProperty('page') ? table.page.info().page : 1; //if table is not init yet (first call) use page 1
        $.ajax({
            data: JSON.stringify({ "pageNum": pageNum }),
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST", //you could use GET and ?page=1 parameter
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "/my/url",
            success: function(data){
                var new_data = JSON.parse(data);
                table.clear();
                table.rows.add(new_data);
                table.draw();
            }
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: Tried this solution with GET and ?page=1 parameter, but the pagination isn't working. It shows all 20 records on a single page despite setting "pageLength": 10, "paging": true, and "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1],[10, 25, 50, "All"]] on the datatable. It was working earlier, not able to figure out what's the issue here. Tried to look up on this but couldn't find any working solution.

Comment: What did you try? Custom ajax handler or ajax from the data table parameter?

Comment: I'm getting the json response on console.log(data) as `[{"name": "XYZ", "branch": "main", "city": "Tokyo", "state": "P3", "country": "Japan", "pin": "110011", "landmark": "L1"},...{"name": "XYZ", "branch": "main", "city": "Tokyo", "state": "P3", "country": "Japan", "pin": "110011", "landmark": "L30"}]` but unable to map it to the table even though the order is same as column names on the datatable.

Comment: Well great, at least now your first issue is resolved: the JSON is now valid. Could you update your question with your full code please?

Comment: I've edited my question with the code, could you please have a look and suggest? I feel like I'm missing some small part but unable to figure out.

Comment: Does your solution 1 sends back the correct datas as for page 2? or is it the same data as page 1 and so would explain why the datatable doesn't display new data? About the solution 2: we see in the JSON that there is a "0" and some other numeric keys. Is the Flask method the same for both solution? If so, check around the JSON decoding of the solution 2. Another test: can u try to clear() and add() and draw() with an hardcoded array? To see if it updates the datatable correctly?

Comment: Solution 2 (suggested by you) is closest to what I'm trying to achieve. Tried to add a sample of 3 records manually like table.rows.add([{"name": "XYZ", "branch": "main", "city": "T", "state": "P3", "country": "J", "pin": "110011", "landmark": "L1"},{"name": "XYZ", "branch": "main", "city": "T", "state": "P3", "country": "J", "pin": "110011", "landmark": "L2"},{"name": "XYZ", "branch": "main", "city": "T", "state": "P3", "country": "J", "pin": "110011", "landmark": "L3"}]); which is exactly as mentioned on https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows.add() but its just displaying 3 blank rows

Comment: Did you call the .draw(); method after? like in the documentation you linked? Is their any JS error ?

Comment: yes table.clear(); followed by table.rows.add([{"name": "XYZ", "branch": "main", "city": "T", "state": "P3", "country": "J", "pin": "110011", "landmark": "L1"},{"name": "XYZ", "branch": "main", "city": "T", "state": "P3", "country": "J", "pin": "110011", "landmark": "L2"},{"name": "XYZ", "branch": "main", "city": "T", "state": "P3", "country": "J", "pin": "110011", "landmark": "L3"}]).draw(); and some "DevTools failed to load SourceMap" warnings but no errors

Comment: Is the table initied empty before you add rows? or already has some data? Can you try with an empty table?

Comment: It already had top 20 rows (2 pages, 10 per page) and on clicking the next page button I need it to clear the table, fetch the top 30 records, and display them (3 pages, 10 per page). The 20 records on startup appear fine. After clicking on next page the table gets emptied by table.clear() but table.rows.add().draw() is not displaying data on table. I'm using render_template html for the first 20 records, and json.dumps() for anything after next page click

Comment: First, why on page 2 you get 30 first rows? Each page should produce 1 request with 10 rows, and only query the current pages rows. So each pagination click should trigger a API request. Can u try init the table without any rows, and then add().draw() some data to confirm this works?